# Database Watchdog

Tags: database, reporting, redshift

I want a tool that can help me admin a Redshift database and notify me when something is out of the ordinary. Example:

1. The growth rate of a table overtime has decreased or significantly increased. This will help understand when the database isn't being filled and identify errors upstream.
2. Relations between columns - for example the difference between the time a message has been generated (a column) and the time it was actually saved (another column). If this difference is too big, something is wrong.

Other requirements:

1. Can send email when something is wrong.
2. Can be scheduled and customized.
3. Doesn't have to be Redshift specific of course, but a plus if it is in the AWS ecosystem (and no, cloudwatch alarms on the cluster is not enough)
4. Best case - if it can talk to Pagerduty.